# What is $f(x')$ in a trigonometrical series?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, partial-differential-equations

I read the book `The Mathematics of Diffusion` by John Crank. In a case, the solution is as a trigonometrical series of

[image]

$x$ is the distance, what is the term $f(x')$?

Shouldn't we calculate the series for any given value of $x$? Then, what is $x'$?

How can the last integral be calculated?

Comment: $x'$ is a new variable used in the Integral, "integration variable"

Comment: I think $x'$ is just an alternate form of $x$, in order to carry out the integration.  The whole expression for $C$ is a constant, so the integral should also return a constant value that does not depend on $x$.

Comment: It's called a dummy variable, or bound variable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables

Comment: @ArnaudMortier does it mean it should be treated as $x$?

Comment: the integral is inside a sigma

Comment: @Isham what do you imply?

Comment: Yes, you could write any letter you want, it lives and makes sense only inside the integral (and it is "declared" by the $dx'$).

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I still don't get it. Imagine we want to solve the equation at $x=0.5$. Then, how does the integral look like?